# How to aggregate data in SQL within nested groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am using PostgreSQL and have a table like this:  See the sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/253b4/1

```
CREATE TABLE usage_sample
(
  id serial primary key, 
  category text NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  sample_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

I need to write a query that returns a count for the number of samples within each minute and have this set of counts for each combination of category and name.  So the output we be something like:

```
cat1, act1, minute1, count
cat1, act1, minute2, count
cat1, act2, minute1, count
cat1, act2, minute3, count
cat2, act1, minute2, count
...
```

I know how to get a count for each minute using group by and how to get a count for each combo of category and action, but I can't figure out how to combine these so I can nest the groupings and counts.

The sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/253b4/1 shows an example data set and the queries I have tried to start with.  Can anyone give me advice on how to get the result I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select category, name, date_trunc('minute', sample_time) as minute, count(*) 
from usage_sample 
group by category, name, date_trunc('minute', sample_time)
order by category, name, minute
```

Comment: That works.  Not quite sure why I didn't see that before.  Thanks.  I have an updated fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/785a0/2